# GCP Log-export pub/sub with multiple sink filters with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to create a terraform module that takes a list of filters as a parameter and creates sinks based on it. I want to use only one pub/sub topic. I have tried to use `for_each` to create sinks based on the filter list, but I end up having `Cycle-error`. Here is terraform website [link](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/log-export/google/latest/submodules/pubsub) for the one filter solution.

This is what I have tried:

```
module "log_export" {
  for_each               = toset(var.log_error_filters) // Terraform list ["filter1", "filter2"]
  source                 = "terraform-google-modules/log-export/google"
  destination_uri        = "${module.destination.destination_uri}"
  filter                 = each.key
  log_sink_name          = "pubsub_example_logsink"
  parent_resource_id     = var.project_id
  parent_resource_type   = "project"
  unique_writer_identity = true
}

module "destination" {
  for_each                 = module.log_export
  source                   = "terraform-google-modules/log-export/google//modules/pubsub"
  project_id               = var.project_id
  topic_name               = "sample-topic"
  log_sink_writer_identity = "${module.log_export[each.key].writer_identity}"
  create_subscriber        = true
}
```

In module "destination", `module.log_export` is a list, and therefore, it needs to be looped, since `log_sink_writer_identity`-field needs to be a string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the issue was to use a multiline string as a Terraform variable that contains filters separated with `OR`. Here is the full solution:

```
module "log_export" {
  source                 = "terraform-google-modules/log-export/google"
  destination_uri        = "${module.destination.destination_uri}"
  filter                 = var.log_error_filters
  log_sink_name          = "pubsub_example_logsink"
  parent_resource_id     = var.project_id
  parent_resource_type   = "project"
  unique_writer_identity = true
}

module "destination" {
  source                   = "terraform-google-modules/log-export/google//modules/pubsub"
  project_id               = var.project_id
  topic_name               = "sample-topic"
  log_sink_writer_identity = "${module.log_export.writer_identity}"
  create_subscriber        = true
}
```

Where `var.log_error_filters` is built like this:

```
log_error_filters         = <<EOF
severity >= ERROR OR
filter2 here
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a list of objects created in another module with another for_each. The writer_identity (as well as any other attributes) are values on the referenced list.

```
module "destination" {
    for_each = module.log_export
    source                   = "terraform-google-modules/log-
                                   export/google//modules/pubsub"
    project_id               = var.project_id
    topic_name               = "sample-topic"
    log_sink_writer_identity = each.value.writer_identity
    create_subscriber        = true
}
```

The syntax of the for_each may need some tweaking for you as references are usually `for_each = <resource>.<name>` i.e `for_each = google_logging_project_sink.my_logging_sinks`